# How Routes static class in Laravel are being invoked by the caller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering how the caller script calls the following codes in Laravel.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // return view('welcome');
    return redirect('public');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/download', 'routinesController@download');
```

You may check the web.php, or api.php in routes folder to see what I mean. This may not actually specific to Laravel but to programming as well. I just want to understand the script how it calls them.

Comment: I sad to know how people down voted without saying anything. Can you answer me how? Can you give example instead?

Answer (score 0):

Its called a Facade php pattern

If you open a `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` it contains all the magic behind how it gets invoke in Laravel.

So simple way to understand is laravel use App container for it.

I hope it make sense